# Laravel 5.2 routing. Struggling for days now

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-routing

I have been sitting for days now and my routing does not want to work.

I installed Laravel on Amazon Linux AMI (about 8 times) and I CANNOT get routing to work.

I added one route to test in routing.php and this works and I see the login page:

```
Route::get('login', function() {
    return View::make('login');
});
```

I copy the same view to a users subfolder and if I do this it does not work.

```
Route::get('login', function() {
    return View::make('users.login');
});
```

Basically it looks like any subfolder I call does not work and I get a 500 error.

I have installed Laravel in the `/var/www folder` and changed the directory and `DocumentRoot` to point to `/var/www/public` folder.

This is my .htaccess file in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Send requests to public directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

My storage and bootstrap folders does have 777 permissions.

I really need help on this one, I am out of options.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `users.login` instead of: `users/login`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have :( I will just edit the post to fix it.

Comment: I opened a trial account with cloudways.com, started up Laravel, copied my stuff and the site works :)

Comment: Then it was probably a file permission issue

Comment: I triple double checked the permissions before moving, so that was not it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After many hours trying to get this done, I figured out that my .htaccess file was the problem.

Just remove any blank space and put the file in UTF8. Sometimes windows add special characters which causes the problem.